# How to delete the rows older then 1 month?

Tags: sql-server

I have One Table Login in this table i want to delete rows older then 1 months.

```
  CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Login] (
  [Id]          INT           IDENTITY (1, 1) NOT NULL,
  [CurrentTime] VARCHAR(MAX) NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED ([Id] ASC)
  );
```

This is my table design.Here I am storing date and time as varchar type.
With using or without using the CurrenTime field how to delete one month older rows

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use `DateAdd`. Try

```
DELETE FROM Table1 WHERE Column < DATEADD(MONTH, -1, GETDATE())
```

or

```
DELETE FROM Table1 WHERE Column < DATEADD(dd,-30,GETDATE())
```

To convert your varchar column to date format use

```
SELECT CONVERT(Datetime, '2015-10-29 15:01:00', 120)
```

Comment: but in my case the column is in varchar type.for that what i do

Comment: if the column type is DateTime means above code is working perfectly

Comment: Why's it varchar instead of `Datetime`?

Comment: i tried to store in DateTime type only but every time it shows some error in my WPF. i changed it into varchar it working without any error

Comment: ya got it...Thank u so much...Aishvarya Karthik

Comment: No problem, glad to help :)

Answer (score 3):

```
DELETE FROM [dbo].[Login]
WHERE [CurrentTime] < DATEADD(month, -1, GETDATE())
```

will work.

Answer (score 2):

Try :

```
DELETE FROM Table1 WHERE DATEDIFF(mm, CAST(COL2 AS DateTime), GETDATE()) > 1
```

Comment: ya i tried this but i got following error    *The conversion of a varchar data type to a datetime data type resulted in an out-of-range value.*

Comment: Did you get this error using the CAST method ? What about using the CONVERT Aishvarya Karthik wrote about ?

Comment: that CONVERT method is working separably but tried with my table means i want to write two query .but urs is only one so if it wont show the error urs query best for me

Comment: Can you provide an example of what's inside your date column ?

Comment: CONVERT(DATETIME, SUBSTRING('28/08/15 2:24:21 PM', 0, 9), 3) It might not be the fastest way of doing it, but as your date format is quite out of the ordinary (i.e. "dd/MM/yy hh:mm:ss AM/PM"), splitting the string in two seemed like the most efficient way for me.